# SQL query to fetch rows which has same IDs but different values in other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am Using the below table

[image]

The `case_id` for two rows. If the case Id is same then I would want to fetch the row that has `Test_script_type` as automation and ignore the manual. How can I achieve it with a SQL query..If there is only manual fetch the manual row. How can I achieve it with a SQL query. The Output would be like : [image]

Help is appreciated. Thanks for your time In-advance

Answer (score 1):

You could adress this with not exists:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where
    script_type = 'Automation'
    or not exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable t1 
        where 
            t1.case_id = t.case_id 
            and t1.script_name <> t.script_name 
            and t1.script_type = 'Automation'
    )
```

You can also filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.script_type = (
    select min(t1.script_type) -- This gives priority to 'Automation' against 'Manual'
    from mytable t1
    where t1.case_id = t.case_id
)
```

Comment: Thank you much. I got the required result. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL Server, You may try below query -

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CASE_ID, SCRIPT_NAME, SCRIPT_TYPE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE_ID ORDER BY SCRIPT_TYPE) RN
      FROM YOUR_TAB) T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Hi, It's fetching automation but when there is only single instance as manual I want that row also to be fetched. I want the output to be as :                       
 Case_id Script_name Script_type
  
101          ABC1                Automation
  
102 XYZ1 Automation
103 PQR Manual
104 Test Manual

Comment: @Aish, What is your Mysql version?

Comment: Am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 16.5.1

Comment: @Aish, Please try below query.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table` t1
LEFT JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.case_id = t2.case_id AND t1.script_type != t2.script_type
WHERE t1.script_type = 'automation' OR t2.case_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT T1.CASE_ID, T1.SCRIPT_NAME, T1.SCRIPT_TYPE,
  COUNT(T1.CASE_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.CASE_ID) AS cnt
  FROM table1 T1
)

SELECT cte.CASE_ID, cte.SCRIPT_NAME, cte.SCRIPT_TYPE
FROM cte
WHERE (cte.cnt > 1 AND UPPER(cte.SCRIPT_TYPE) = UPPER('AUTOMATION'))
OR cte.cnt = 1
```

The `WITH` statement adds a column counting how many times the case_id value is duplicated, which helps identify the rows you want to work with.

Here is an example of it working with the data you have provided: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49e7f/11)